# The sum of two independent variables following the Binomial Distributions

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I would have thought the answer to the following was another Binomial distribution, but I can't seem to get Mathematica to output that fact:

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[x1 + x2, {x1, x2} \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]], y]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is slighlty off. The way you wrote it, `{x1, x2} \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]]` indicates that the vector variable `{x1, x2}` follows the *multivariate* distribution `BinomialDistribution[n, p]`, which of course does not work.

Instead, you need to indicate the distribution for each variable:

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[
  x1 + x2, {x1 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
   x2 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]}], y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is shown in the second syntax example in the [documentation for `TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html).

[Bob Hanlon](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9362/bob-hanlon) also pointed out that a more readable result can be obtained by evaluating the `TransformedDistribution` itself:

```
TransformedDistribution[x1 + x2,
 {x1 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p],
  x2 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]}
]

(* Out: BinomialDistribution[2 n, p] *)
```

Comment: Evaluation of just `TransformedDistribution[
 x1 + x2, {x1 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
  x2 \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]}]` gives `BinomialDistribution[2 n, p]` which makes it clear that the result is a `BinomialDistribution` rather than having to visually recognize the fact from the `PDF`. And on my system, your input evaluates to `Piecewise[{{(1 - p)^(2*n - y)*p^y*
         Binomial[2*n, y], 
       0 <= y <= 2*n}}, 0]`

Comment: @Bob Both are excellent points, thank you. I added the result of evaluation of `TransformedDistribution` as it is indeed more readable, and fixed the output image, which I had copied wrong.

Comment: `{x1, x2} \[Distributed] ...` would be fine with multinomial distributions. The form of `Distributed` must follow each distribution individually, though.

Comment: @kirma I don't understand your point. Could you elaborate on your second sentence?

Comment: For instance, look at `MultinomialDistribution` documentation. Single value distributions work with single variable, others demand list of correct length... but you can't trivially combine them.

Answer (score 3):

For joint distribution of `n` iid random variables each with distribution `d`, you can also use `ProductDistribution[{d, n}]`.

```
TransformedDistribution[x1 + x2, 
  {x1, x2} \[Distributed] ProductDistribution@{BinomialDistribution[n, p], 2}]
```

> BinomialDistribution[2 n, p]

```
PDF[dist, y] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  p^y \binom{2 n}{y} (1-p)^{2 n-y} & 0\leq y\leq 2 n \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$